# "dyld: Library not loaded" error when using Alamofire in tvOS Top Shelf Extension on device

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, alamofire, tvos

I've built a [Top Shelf Extension](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/documentation/TVServices/Reference/TVServices_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016412) for my tvOS app. It works properly in the Simulator. When I run it on the device (Dev Kit running tvOS beta 3) and I try to load the Top Shelf Extension, my app gets a fatal error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire
  Referenced from: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/5EF46962-235C-4330-9723-623E80E3D8BE/MyApp.app/PlugIns/MyApp TV Services Extension.appex/MyApp TV Services Extension
Reason: image not found
```

I'm using Xcode 7.1 beta 3, Cocoapods 0.39.0, and Alamofire 3.0.0 off the ["tvOS" branch](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/tree/tvOS). My `Podfile` is as follows:

```
platform :tvos, '9.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'MyApp' do

end

target 'MyApp TV Services Extension' do
  pod 'Alamofire', :git => 'https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git', :branch => 'tvOS'
  pod 'SwiftyJSON', :git => 'https://github.com/jeffbowen/SwiftyJSON.git', :commit => 'fa3fc27c14602e43f69e8d70da4fc2f9a084a987'
end
```

Not sure if this is an issue with Alamofire, Cocoapods, or tvOS beta 3. I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out you have to include the pods needed for the extension in the main target as well. It's now working for me and here's what my `Podfile` looks like:

```
platform :tvos, '9.0'
use_frameworks!

def shared_pods
  pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.0'
  pod 'SwiftyJSON', :git => 'https://github.com/jeffbowen/SwiftyJSON.git', :commit => 'fa3fc27c14602e43f69e8d70da4fc2f9a084a987'
end

target 'MyApp' do
  shared_pods
end

target 'MyApp TV Services Extension' do
  shared_pods
end
```

I learned the `shared_pods` trick [here](http://natashatherobot.com/cocoapods-installing-same-pod-multiple-targets/).

Comment: Note that it is no longer necessary to specify the tvOS branch as it has been merged with the main branch.

Answer (score 1):

You need to delete your **device and provisioning provisioning certificate** from your developer account and create **new certificate** for both. After creating certificate download that certificate and drag into the key-chain access. now you can able to see you new certificate with name(**Don't forgot to delete previous certificate and remove from key-chain also**) so now your work is done and go to :-

1. Go to xcode select team developer account.
2. Go to code sign in select as **ios developer**(in code signing identity and select      developer profile for any ios sdk for both **debug and release**).
3. Set Embedded-content-contains swift code to **Yes** by default is **NO**
4. Delete app from device.
5. **Shift + Command + k** to clean the build.
6. **Command + B** to create new build.
7. Once Build is successful...now you can run(**Command + R**) and its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to have this in your podfile:

```
link_with 'MyAppName'
```

I  have used Alamofire and it works when used with this tvOs project to display YouTube videos found [here](https://github.com/klein-thibault/StarcraftWatch)

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working for me. I'm getting the same problems as @Jeff.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @frakman1. `link_with` didn't work for me though. Got it working by including the pods in both the extension target as well as my main target. Check out the answer I just added, @nortchuck.